# WordPress REST API not working when filtering by slug using Axios

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, axios

I was able to display WordPress post content using axios and Vue.js. Once I switched to filtering by slug, I was unable to display post content.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <article>
    <h2 class="subtitle">{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
    <div v-html="post.excerpt.rendered"></div>
  </article>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Router from 'vue-router'

export default {
  name: 'ShowPost',
  data () {
    return {
      post: []
    }
  },
  created() {
           this.slug = this.$route.params.slug;
       },
  mounted() {
           axios({ method: "GET", "url": "https://wpdemo.stevensoehl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=" + this.slug }).then(json => {
               this.post = json.data;
           }, error => {
               console.error(error);
           });
       }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I used postman with your api url and was able to return hello-world using the slug. Is it possible that this.slug is somehow parsed so it doesn't match any longer? try making some more test posts and see if any of them get returned

Comment: check the network panel in the debug console, what is the url?

Comment: Daniel- I checked the network panel & the response tab is showing the correct response based on the url however the post content is not displayed. It displays post content when using post id

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to check whether there is cross domain problem in the console, and there may be no cross domain problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a solution. In my links to an individual post I carried over the slug and id as params

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'ShowPost', params: {slug: post.slug, id:post.id}}">{{ post.title.rendered }}</router-link>
```

Route is slug and filter response by id. It now works as planned.

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: 'ShowPost',
  data () {
    return {
      post: []
    }
  },
  created() {
           this.id = this.$route.params.id;
       },
  mounted() {
           axios({ method: "GET", "url": "https://wpdemo.stevensoehl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/" + this.id }).then(json => {
               this.post = json.data;
           }, error => {
               console.error(error);
           });
       }
}
```